# SQL MATCH ... AGAINST limits result to current year

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stumped by this:

Two commands:

```sh
SELECT Date,Sentence FROM exampletable;
```

```sh
SELECT Date,Sentence FROM exampletable WHERE MATCH (Sentence) AGAINST ("South" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE );
```

The first gives me results for the entire database, beginning in 2013. I see that there's an entry sometime in 2018 that contains the word "South", so using a `match` `against` in the second command I know I should get at least one result pre 2020. However, the first result is from 2020-01-28 onwards.

This happens in all examples I try. Simply adding a `match` `against` limits my returned results to > 2020. Is there some database setting that I'm not aware of? Or just something plainly obvious?

Any help would be appreciated! (I'm using MySQL 5.7)

Comment: Check `SELECT Date,Sentence, MATCH (Sentence) AGAINST ("South" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS MatchValue FROM exampletable`

Comment: Check your callation. 'south' might be not equal to 'South'.

Comment: Have you tried using like instead of match?

Comment: Please create and post a minimal reproducible example. You only need to post one row that should be returned but is not.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, you're correct here with the collation. Switching to small "south" works. I'm trying to figure out how this could have changed just for entries beginning this year, when I haven't touched the db at all!?

Comment: Rebuilding my fulltext indexes seems to have solved this.

Comment: @babno I think his exercise is about efficiency. Like isn’t prefered

Answer (score 1):

Your query has no `order by`.  Have you tried something like this?

```
SELECT Date, Sentence
FROM exampletable
WHERE MATCH (Sentence) AGAINST ("South" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE )
ORDER BY date;
```

Perhaps the earlier dates are just later in the result set.

Comment: The results I get back are all of them unfortunately.